# Nan Result from javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi this is my first post and my first attempt at javascript (I'm into php). The problem is that I am getting a NaN result from my js which follows (if I can get the code thingy to graft!)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Running_Total() { 
        alert('firing');
        var cost1 = "'.$_SESSION['75gmcost'].'"+""; 
        var cost2 = "'.$_SESSION['100gmcost'].'"+""; 
        var cost3 = "'.$_SESSION['1kgcost'].'";+""; 
        var cost4 = "'.$_SESSION['c75gmcost'].'"+""; 
        var qty1 = "'.$_SESSION['qty75gm'].'"+""; 
        var qty2 = "'.$_SESSION['qty100gm'].'"+""; 
        var qty3 = "'.$_SESSION['qty1kg'].'"+""; 
        var qty4 = "'.$_SESSION['qtyc75gm'].'"+""; 
        var sum = 0;
        sum += cost1 * qty1;
        sum += cost2 * qty2;
        sum += cost3 * qty3;
        sum += cost4 * qty4;
        $('#tot_cost').empty();
        $('#tot_cost').append(sum);
    }
</script>
```

I am attempting to sum order totals from form input, but don't know enough about js to solve the Nan problem.
I guess that my php variables must be altered to suit js, but haven't got a clue what to do? ##

Comment: Is that your generated source? As it looks to me like your not actually echoing out the value of any of the $_SESSION variables, you're just writing the string $_SESSION... try changing the lines to

var cost1 = '<?php echo $_SESSION["75gmcost"]; ?>';

Comment: No it's source I wrote (diving in at the deep end) - I'll try the echo method suggested...

Comment: Thanks TommyBs! I got a result - 0! So my new problem is why doesn't my arithmetic work? Ho-hum...

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the var assignments in your code with this:

```
var cost1 = {$_SESSION['75gmcost']};
var cost2 = {$_SESSION['100gmcost']};
var cost3 = {$_SESSION['1kgcost']}; 
var cost4 = {$_SESSION['c75gmcost']}; 
var qty1 = {$_SESSION['qty75gm']};
var qty2 = {$_SESSION['qty100gm']}; 
var qty3 = {$_SESSION['qty1kg']};
var qty4 = {$_SESSION['qtyc75gm']};
```

Concatinating the strings results in a value that is not a interpreted as a number (NaN) in JavaScript.

Here's a working example that alerts '4'

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['75gmcost'] = 1; 
    $_SESSION['100gmcost'] = 1;  
    $_SESSION['1kgcost'] = 1; 
    $_SESSION['c75gmcost'] = 1; 
    $_SESSION['qty75gm'] = 1;  
    $_SESSION['qty100gm'] = 1; 
    $_SESSION['qty1kg'] = 1; 
    $_SESSION['qtyc75gm'] = 1; 

    print <<< HERE
           <script type="text/javascript">
    function Running_Total() { 
            alert('firing');
        var cost1 = {$_SESSION['75gmcost']}; 
        var cost2 = {$_SESSION['100gmcost']};
        var cost3 = {$_SESSION['1kgcost']};
        var cost4 = {$_SESSION['c75gmcost']}; 
        var qty1 = {$_SESSION['qty75gm']};
        var qty2 = {$_SESSION['qty100gm']}; 
        var qty3 = {$_SESSION['qty1kg']};
        var qty4 = {$_SESSION['qtyc75gm']}; 
        var sum = 0;
        sum += cost1 * qty1;
        sum += cost2 * qty2;
        sum += cost3 * qty3;
        sum += cost4 * qty4;
        alert(sum);
    }
    Running_Total();
    </script>
    HERE;
?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure those `{ ... }` are invalid there. And `$_SESSION` would be interpreted as JS variable, which probably does not exist.

Comment: @FelixKling The brackets are only interpreted during PHP execution. Once JS executes, the brackets will have been replaced with the actual values.

Comment: Since when does PHP do this? Do you have a reference?

Comment: I'm assuming tHe PHP opening and closing tags have been omitted.

Comment: You mean the whole code would be inclosed in `<?php ... ?>`? Wouldn't  `var cost1` produce a syntax error in PHP then? I don't believe braces are valid at the right hand side of an assignment in PHP either.

Comment: Something like that I guess, because using the suggestion instead of echo'ing  them out causes the script not to fire...

Comment: That makes more sense now... thanks for updating. But just be correct: The string concatenation is not the problem, the value of the string was the problem.

Comment: @FelixKling No problem. Thanks for helping clarify this.

Comment: Any suggestions re the arithmetic totaling 0(zero) - wouldn't this indicate that the js is not picking up valid values from my session variables?

Comment: It's OK - I've found the problem - qty75gm (etc) only get's set up in the session variables after the js has fired! (MY bad) thanks for your help - all of you!!

Comment: Just to attempt closure on this, is there a mechanism whereby I can fire the Running_Total script AFTER onclick process has finished? (i.e. is there perhaps a parameter I can add to the onclick to facilitate this?

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this (you can see the results here: http://jorgecardoso.eu/temp/test.php):

```
<html>
<head>

<?php
     // just to test
session_start();
$_SESSION['75gmcost'] = 1;
$_SESSION['100gmcost'] = 1;
$_SESSION['1kgcost'] = 1;
$_SESSION['c75gmcost'] = 1;
$_SESSION['qty75gm'] = 1;
$_SESSION['qty100gm'] = 1;
$_SESSION['qty1kg'] = 1;
$_SESSION['qtyc75gm'] = 1;
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Running_Total() {
        alert('firing');
        var cost1 = <?php echo $_SESSION['75gmcost'] ?>;
        var cost2 = <?php echo $_SESSION['100gmcost'] ?>;
        var cost3 = <?php echo $_SESSION['1kgcost'] ?>;
        var cost4 = <?php echo $_SESSION['c75gmcost'] ?>;
        var qty1 =  <?php echo $_SESSION['qty75gm'] ?>;
        var qty2 = <?php echo $_SESSION['qty100gm'] ?>;
        var qty3 = <?php echo $_SESSION['qty1kg'] ?>;
        var qty4 = <?php echo $_SESSION['qtyc75gm'] ?>;
        var sum = 0;
        sum += cost1 * qty1;
        sum += cost2 * qty2;
        sum += cost3 * qty3;
        sum += cost4 * qty4;
        alert( sum);
//        $('#tot_cost').empty();
//        $('#tot_cost').append(sum);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
Running_Total();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```